Include custom taxonomy created via ACF in Woocommerce product search
I created a book store and created "Author" taxonomies using advanced custom fields.
I would like to improve my product search results on Woocommerce. Now it's like an author's books only appear in search results when their name appears in the title or product description.
I would like the search results to show all books related to a given author after entering his name.
I'm testing code I found on the forum: Enable custom taxonomies in WooCommerce product search
Unfortunately, it does not affect search results in any way.
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended', 999, 2 );
function woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended( $search, $query ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp;

    $qvars = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
    && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
    && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
        return $search;
    }
    
    // Here set your custom taxonomy
    $taxonomy = 'autorzy'; // WooCommerce product tag

    // Get the product Ids
    $ids = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'tax_query'       => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
        )),
    ));

    if ( count( $ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}


Sorry, but the code still works perfectly with WooCommerce product Tags, Categories or Brands for example (which are custom WooCommerce taxonomies). So the problem comes from your custom taxonomy "autorzy" created using ACF.

Do you have an idea how to combine one with the other?

@LoicTheAztec ACF just provides a GUI for creating taxonomies. They are registered no different than using a custom register_taxonomy method - since that's what ACF uses in it's ACF_Taxonomy class.

@disinfor Maybe, but the fact is that the OP code (picked from an answer I made) works with custom product taxonomies. People using ACF often get through specific issues, that doesn't occur with hand made classic code. You can see that through all related threads tagged advanced-custom_fields

@LoicTheAztec my comment was simply informational. I use ACF on every site, and yes there are some idiosyncrasies, but I'm also not sure of the taxonomy creation, since I've never used that feature - based on the code, it seems like it would work exactly the same as a custom code solution.

@LoicTheAztec As a developer, I use it and encourage use for certain features :)

@LoicTheAztec I manually created a brand taxonomy to check and unfortunately the products are still not shown in the search results.

@LoicTheAztec Can you show the full code? Both the one registering the taxonomies and the one expanding the search?

@LoicTheAztec I received it, tested it. It didn't work. Maybe I misinterpreted something and the code works. Finally, I used a plug-in that expanded the power options.

@PatrykBanach For sure, it doesn't work "when their name appears in the title or product description", but works for "the search results to show all books related to a given author after entering his name" directly in the search.
